# Can I rotate column header in Syncfusion GridDataControl?

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

I'm using SyncFusion WPF controls; I need to rotate some column headers of GridDataControl to minimize columns' widths as the data in those columns are just one character long. I'm unable to find a way, I also looked at the Demos but nothing gained, can anyone help me out here? Can it even be possible in this grid? I was possible in DevExpress XtraGrid but their WPF grid is of no use to me, so I had to shift to some other developer.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by rotating Column Header?
Why not try playing with ColumnSizer for GridDataControl to Auto/SizeToCell/SizeToHeader to minimize the Column Width?

```
        <syncfusion:GridDataControl x:Name="dataGrid"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding OrderList}"
                                    ColumnSizer="Auto"
                                    VisualStyle="Metro">
```